# Getting "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" when working with Excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have an Excel file in which for one of the columns (x) rows are filled with dictionary. Any action performed on this column is giving me this error: df.x , df.x.describe(). Impossible to work on it.

I've checked by creating the same df manually, in order to check if it is not the type problem, but no.

```
b=[{'maker':'renault','model':'twingo','year':'null','motor':'null','fitment':'null'}]
c=[5500]
df= pd.DataFrame({'country':a, 'x':b ,'sold':c})
```

Have you encountered a similar problem?

Here is the full error message:

```
<ipython-input-11-04b9e65f2265> in <module>
      1 maker=[]
----> 2 for idx, row in test['x'].iteritems():
      3     l=row.keys()
      4 
      5     if 'maker' in l:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2774                 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2775                     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2776                 return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2777 
   2778         # Do we have a slicer (on rows)?

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   3584         res = cache.get(item)
   3585         if res is None:
-> 3586             values = self._data.get(item)
   3587             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   3588             cache[item] = res

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in get(self, item)
    966                         raise ValueError("cannot label index with a null key")
    967 
--> 968             return self.iget(loc)
    969         else:
    970 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in iget(self, i)
    983         Otherwise return as a ndarray
    984         """
--> 985         block = self.blocks[self._blknos[i]]
    986         values = block.iget(self._blklocs[i])
    987 

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. I've made an error  when renaming columns.
Thanks